# Input Mismatch Exception while reading file

Tags: java, eclipse, exception, input, filereader

So far this is the code I have. I am trying to read a text file into my demo program and read each line separately into another class. The code for whatever reason adds an empty line between the first rank and next name line which in term causes my program to fail because the nextInt() command reads a String because of the empty line. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks guys.

TEXT FILE:

```
David Wise
USA
SKI HALFPIPE MENS
1
Mike Riddle
Canada
SKI HALFPIPE MENS
2
Kevin Rolland
France
SKI HALFPIPE MENS
3
Maddie Bowman
USA
SKI HALPIPE WOMENS 
1
Marie Martinod
France
SKI HALPIPE WOMENS 
2
Ayana Onozuka
Japan
SKI HALPIPE WOMENS 
3
Felix Loch
Germany
LUGE SINGLE MENS
1
Albert Demchenko
Russia
LUGE SINGLE MENS
2
Armin Zoeggeler
Italy
LUGE SINGLE MENS
3
Natalie Geisenberger
Germany
LUGE SINGLE WOMENS
1
Tatjana Huefner
Germany
LUGE SINGLE WOMENS
2
Erin Hamlin
USA
LUGE SINGLE WOMENS
3
Alexander Tretiakov
Russia
SKELETON MENS
1
Martins Dukurs
Latvia
SKELETON MENS
2
Mathew Antoine
USA
SKELETON MENS
3
Elizabeth Yarnold
United Kingdom
SKELETON WOMENS
1
Noelle Pikus-Pace
USA
SKELETON WOMENS
2
Elena Nikitina
Russia
SKELETON WOMEN
3
Michel Mulder
Russia
500M SPEED SKATING MENS
1
Jan Smeekens
Russia
500M SPEED SKATING MENS
2
Ronald Mulder
Russia
500M SPEED SKATING MENS
3
```

DEMO PROGRAM:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import ch06.lists.*;
import support.*;

public class OlympicDemo 
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
    ListInterface<String> list = new ArrayIndexedList<String>();
    final String FILEINNAME = "src/AthleteInformation.txt";

    String name = "";
    String country = "";
    String event = "";
    int rank = 0;

    Athlete athletes;
    OlympicAthletes olympic;

    try
    {
        FileReader file = new FileReader(FILEINNAME);
        Scanner ath = new Scanner(file);

        while(ath.hasNext())
        {
            name = ath.nextLine();
            System.out.println(name);
            country = ath.nextLine();
            System.out.println(country);
            event = ath.nextLine();
            System.out.println(event);
            rank = ath.nextInt();
            System.out.println(rank);

            athletes = new Athlete(name, country, event, rank);
        }
    }
    catch(FileNotFoundException e)
    {
        System.out.println("FILE: " + FILEINNAME + " DOES NOT EXIST");
    }

    /**
    try
    {
        ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(new
                FileInputStream(FILEINNAME));

        athletes = (Athlete)in.readObject();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("FILE: " + FILEINNAME + " DOES NOT EXIST");
    }
    */
    }
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
David Wise
USA
SKI HALFPIPE MENS
1

Mike Riddle
Canada
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
    at OlympicDemo.main(OlympicDemo.java:34)
```

Answer (score 0):

After you read the int with `.nextInt()`, the cursor is just after int and not yet on the next new line. Therefore, calling `.nextLine()` at that point just gives you an empty string.

After you read in an integer with `nextInt()`, call `ath.nextLine();` to put the cursor in the right place before reading the next person's name.